# How to select certain ranges for certain cases?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have the user select a certain range (input, output, or p), and copy their selected cells into a new worksheet. I already have the latter half, but am having trouble creating a function to do the first part.

In short, if the user wants to see input, they will select the input "option", then my code will highlight only cells C8 through F8, and copy into a new worksheet. If they choose output, then my code will highlight only cells H8 through K8, and so on. I am new to VBA!

I have tried using an If statement and looked briefly into Case.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim outputRange As Range
Dim pRange As Range

Set inputRange = Range(Range("C8"), Range("F8"))
Set outputRange = Range(Range("H8"), Range("K8"))
Set pRange = Range(Range("M8"), Range("P8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track here with a `select case` statement.

The below will ask the user to type in 1 to 3 to select which range gets copied and then adds a sheet and copies it to the same address as the range on sheet 1. That's probably not the ideal place to put it, but I'll let you handle the destination address.

```
Public Sub selectRange()

Dim cpyRng As Range
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sIn As String

Set sht1 = ActiveSheet
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
sht2.Name = "CopiedData"

    sIn = Application.InputBox("Please select 1 to 3" & vbLf & vbLf & _
    "1. Input" & vbLf & _
    "2. Output" & vbLf & _
    "3. P", "Enter a value", 1)
    If sIn = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    With sht1
        Select Case sIn
            Case 1
                Set cpyRng = .Range([c8], [f8])  'do what you want for each case
            Case 2
                Set cpyRng = .Range([h8], [k8])
            Case 3
                Set cpyRng = .Range([m8], [p8])
            Case Else
                dummy = MsgBox("wrong input", vbCritical)
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        End With
    End If

cpyRng.Copy Destination:=sht2.Range(cpyRng.Address)

End Sub
```